# jQuery: Adding a class to <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I would like to add a class to the links in the main navigation using jQuery.

This is how the code currently looks:

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">
<a title="Home" href="www.example.com">Home</a>
</li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

And this is what I'd like to achieve:

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">
<a title="Home" href="www.example.com" class="new-class-goes-here">Home</a>
</li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method and the appropriate selector for the `<a>` tags:

```
$(".nav-menu a").addClass("new-class-goes-here");
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/bKLpx/) is a jsFiddle to demonstrate.